# Writing a lua C module for Lua 5.X

Tags: c, lua

I'm trying to write a Lua module that works with Lua 5.0.x-5.4.x. Since every minor version seems to introduce and poorly documented changes to the C API that break backwards compatibility, I would like to know how I can achieve this with the least amount of conditional compilation based on Lua version.

E.g. here's something that should work for Lua 5.1 but not for later versions:

```
#define LUA_LIB
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

static int foo(lua_State *L)
{
  int a = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
  int b = luaL_checknumber(L, 2);

  lua_pushnumber(L, a + b);

  return 1;    
}

luaL_Reg foolib[] = {
  {"foo", foo},
  {NULL, NULL}
};

LUALIB_API int luaopen_foo(lua_State *L)
{
  luaL_register(L, foolib);
  return 1;
}
```

How can I adapt this to work with Lua5.2 onwards? And maybe even make it robust against future API changes?

Comment: Had looked at `Lua` changes from `5.1` to `5.4`(the today version), imo you'd better use different files for each version. If I would've cared about supporting all `Lua` versions, I'd did so.

Comment: Can you give an example of a poorly-documented incompatibility that you've ever found? All of the incompatibilities I've ever ran into upgrading Lua were extremely well-documented.

Comment: Take a look at Compat-5.3 [here](https://github.com/keplerproject/lua-compat-5.3), which has most of the conditional compilation stuff already set up for you (at least up to Lua 5.3). There may be a Lua 5.4 version in the future (there's an open issue for that), but there are not that many C API changes (that can be fixed via conditional compilation) between 5.3 and 5.4. Also, the `LUA_LIB` and `LUALIB_API` macros are intended for the auxilliary Lua API functions, not for 3rd party extension modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following piece of code should get you started:

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include "compat-5.3.h"


static int foo(lua_State* L)
{
  lua_Integer a = luaL_checkinteger(L, 1);
  lua_Integer b = luaL_checkinteger(L, 2);
  lua_pushinteger(L, a + b);
  return 1;
}


static luaL_Reg const foolib[] = {
  { "foo", foo },
  { 0, 0 }
};


#ifndef FOO_API
#define FOO_API
#endif

FOO_API int luaopen_foo(lua_State* L)
{
  luaL_newlib(L, foolib);
  return 1;
}
```

It relies on the C-API port of the [Compat-5.3](https://github.com/keplerproject/lua-compat-5.3/tree/master/c-api) project, and compiles and runs on Lua 5.1 - 5.4. Compat-5.3 provides Lua 5.3 compatibility for Lua 5.1 and 5.2. All you need is the header and C source file. For single source file modules you can just include the header, for multi source file modules you should additionally define a preprocessor symbol and compile/link the `compat-5.3.c` file separately. See the [README.md](https://github.com/keplerproject/lua-compat-5.3#c-code) for details. There are plans to start a Compat-5.4 project (see [this issue](https://github.com/keplerproject/lua-compat-5.3/issues/48)), but the Lua 5.4 C API is mostly compatible to Lua 5.3 anyway.

For Lua 5.0 support you are on your own, unfortunately.

Comment: This is very handy. I still think it's unfortunate that the need for a solution like this even exists but at least it works.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works unchanged in Lua 5.2+ if you change

```
luaL_register(L, foolib);
```

to

```
luaL_newlib(L, foolib);
```

If you need to cater for Lua 5.0 and Lua 5.1, you'll need a compat header. I recommend that you write code for the latest version of Lua and write compatibility macros for the previous versions. See [my libraries](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/%7Elhf/ftp/lua/) for examples.